# Run a test based off the class name in a multi-project gradle project without specifying the project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, testing, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Here is a simplified version of the project:

```
/root
-- /project1
 --- /CoolPackage
  ---- /tests
    ---- MyTest.kt

-- /project2
 --- /NotCoolPackage
  ---- /tests
    ---- TheOtherTest.kt
```

We have tagged some of our tests as "integration-tests" like this
`@Tag("integration-test")`

Pretend that `MyTest` and `TheOtherTest` have that tag.

Here is the custom gradle task

```
fun TaskContainerScope.integrationTestsNamedTask(taskName: String) {
    val testName = project.property("testName") as String
    println(testName)
    register<Test>(taskName) {
        description = "Run specific integration test"
        shouldRunAfter("test")
        minHeapSize = "512m"
        maxHeapSize = "1024m"
        useJUnitPlatform {
            filter {
                includeTags("integration-test")
            }
        }
        setTestNameIncludePatterns(listOf("*${testName}"))
    }
}
```

If I run
`./gradlew -PtestName="MyTest" :project1:integration-test-named`
everything works as expected.

If I run `./gradlew -PtestName="MyTest" integration-test-named` I get an error because gradle looks in `project2` for MyTest.  I need to specify the sub project that the test is in in order for it to work.

Is it possible to not need to specify which project a particular test is in?

Answer (score 0):

A friend was able to help me out.  You can set

```
setFailOnNoMatchingTests(false)
```

as an option to the JUnit configurator.

So in Kotlin:

```
fun TaskContainerScope.integrationTestsNamedTask(taskName: String) {
    val testName = project.property("testName") as String
    println(testName)
    register<Test>(taskName) {
        description = "Run specific integration test"
        shouldRunAfter("test")
        minHeapSize = "512m"
        maxHeapSize = "1024m"
        useJUnitPlatform {
            filter {
                includeTags("integration-test")
                isFailOnNoMatchingTests = false
            }
        }
        setTestNameIncludePatterns(listOf("*${testName}"))
    }
}
```

Notice the

```
isFailOnNoMatchingTests = false
```